# In how many possible combinations can you add 5 numbers?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose, I have 5 numbers, A,B,C,D and E.

My requirement is to add any of the numbers with any one or more of the other numbers?

For example,
I can do A+B, or A+B+C, or B+C+E, or B+C+D+E, etc.

I want to know how many such combinations are possible, and what are the steps to determine the combinations?

Since this is an addition, A+B and B+A are the same, and should not be treated as 2 distinct combinations.

I want to know the formula and the sequence / steps so that I can find answer for any n numbers.

I have arrived at the combinations for 3 numbers (A,B,C) as follows:

A+B,
A+C,
B+C,
A+B+C

Note that B+A, C+A, C+B, B+C+A, etc are not considered, as they are duplicates of existing combinations as there is no place value in addition.

Comment: ${{{{2^n-n-1}}}}$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to arrive at the combination values. I need to know not only the count, but also the distinct combinations, as I am developing a utility software. And how did you arrive at the formula for the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to computing subsets of the set $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ that consist of at least 2 elements, since each such subset (for example the set $\{A,C,E\}$ corresponds to one way of forming a sum.

The number of all subsets of a set with $n$ elements is $2^n$ (for every element you have two options: include it in the subset or leave it out, which gives you $2^n$ different options to form a set). There is one subset with $0$ elements, the empty set, and there are $n$ subsets with $1$ element (the singleton sets), so that indeed gives us the answer $2^n-n-1$, or in your specific case of $n=5$, we get $32-5-1=26$.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation. I also need to know the elements of all the 2^n - n - 1 sets. Can you please help with that.

Comment: If I have to put it in an algorithm, what is the most efficient algorithm suitable for programming, to determine all such sets.

Comment: I am no programmer, so I do not know what the most efficient algorithm suitable for programming for this is. Also I'm not 100% sure if I understand correctly what your question really is. Do you want to implement an algorithm that takes a finite set and returns an array of all its subsets of cardinality at least 2?

I think this is a typical dynamic programming problem. The brute-force recursion will run very slowly, but a memoized version should be able to run much faster. If you dont know what I am talking about, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk is a cool introduction.